# apache poi 4 NoClassDefFoundError occurs (When you try to use CTFtnEndn)

Tags: gradle, apache-poi

I got a jar as a gradle.

```
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '4.1.2'
```

But when I try to use "CTFtnEndn", I have the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTFtnEdn due to missing dependency org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTPerm
```

[image]

I don't know why this error occurs.
(Other functions using "Apache POI" besides CTFtnEndn work. - Create documents, add images, etc.)

I wish I could get some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try adding the dependency `org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.4`? It is a (very large) jar of pretty much everything Microsoft has specified, though POI only uses a subset of it.

Comment: Does http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025 cover you?